# Datalore local installation to Docker postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, datalore

I'm following the directions from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datalore/install-datalore-enterprise.html#basic-datalore-installation) and I've gotten this far...

Prerequisites:
Docker Compose version v2.10.2

1. Clone or download the content of [this repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/datalore-configs/tree/2022.2.3).
2. **Do the following to set up your database:**
   Open docker-compose.yaml in the [repository_folder]/docker-compose folder in any text editor and replace the values of DB_PASSWORD and POSTGRES_PASSWORD properties with any random string (both properties must have the same value). This string will be used as your database password. Make sure you keep it secret.
3. **Run the following command and wait for Datalore to start up:** docker compose up

It's at this point I get the following message:

```
[+] Running 0/2
 - postgresql Error                                                                               0.8s
 - datalore Error                                                                                 0.8s
Error response from daemon: manifest for jetbrains/datalore-server:2022.3 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

I'm completely void of ideas for what to try or where to look for more details to even get started other than emailing support at Jetbrains directly (which I've done).  The only thing I can think of is that there's some unspoken prerequisite that I'm not aware of because the instructions don't really seem that complicated to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cloned master branch with datalore-server 2022.3, which is not released yet. You need to either clone an older version (like 2022.2.3) or edit your /docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml and change the image tags there:

```
  datalore:
    image: jetbrains/datalore-server:2022.2.3
  [...]
  postgresql:
    image: jetbrains/datalore-postgres:2022.2.3
```